# "Email" error on Windows 10 login

Tags: windows-10

I purchased a 2nd hand laptop, and since I've been using it, about 3 minutes after login, I receive the error:

> There is no email program associated to perform the requested action.
>   Please install an email program or, if one is already installed,
>   create an association in the Default Programs control panel.

[image]

If I check Task Manager, I see:

[image]

I have checked Task Manager > Startup and found no unusual items.

I've chatted with MS Support, and they removed some remnants of Microsoft Office from the system, including removing Microsoft Outlook from `HKLM\Software\Clients\Mail`.

How do I remove this error on startup?

Autoruns showed this entry in the Logon tab, which I deselected, but the issue remains:

[image]

Comment: Also check in the Task Scheduler

Comment: What is the question ? Do you want email client or do you want to get rid of unwanted software on the laptop ?

Comment: You do understand, that isn't a start-up entry, so that's just simply a legacy entry for Windows Mail that exists for whatever reason.